# Poll for a result n times (with delays between attempts) before failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, bluebird

We need to write a Node.js function that polls a certain API endpoint for a result of a previously requested calculation.  The result takes a random time to be generated and may not me generated at all.  We'd like to get it as soon as possible, but also I don't want to wait for too long, which means that after a certain number of API calls we'd like the function to fail (reject a Promise).

There is one way communication between our code and the API.

```
const Bluebird = require('bluebird');

function getResult() {
  return new Bluebird(async function (resolve, reject) {

    let counter = 0;

    while (counter < 10) {
      await Bluebird.delay(1000);

      const res = await apiCall();
      if (res.data) {
        resolve(res.data);
      } else {
        counter += 1;
      }
    }

    reject('timeout');
  });
}
```

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. This is the async/await version of the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)! It won't even stop the loop when you call `resolve`, or reject when an exception is thrown (e.g. when `res` is `null`).
You should use

```
async function getResult() {
  for (let counter = 0; counter < 10; counter += 1) {
    await Bluebird.delay(1000);
    const res = await apiCall();
    if (res.data) {
      return res.data;
    }
  }
  throw new Error('timeout');
}
```

If you want to ensure that a Bluebird promise is returned, not a native one, wrap it in [`Bluebird.method`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.method.html) or tell your transpiler to use Bluebird.

Comment: Thanks!  We have `global.Promise = require("bluebird");`. It's good to replace native promises also, right?

Comment: @krl I see, only in real ES6 that shouldn't affect `async` functions. If your transpiler uses the `global.Promise` variable, then that's exactly what I meant though :-)