# Can't throw error from within an async promise executor function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I've been trying to get a conceptual understanding of why the following code doesn't catch the `throw`. If you remove the `async` keyword from the `new Promise(async (resolve, ...` part then it works fine, so it has to do with the fact that the Promise executor is an async function.

```
(async function() {

  try {
    await fn();
  } catch(e) {
    console.log("CAUGHT fn error -->",e)
  }

})();

function fn() {

  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    // ...
    throw new Error("<<fn error>>");
    // ...
  });

}
```

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703241/promise-constructor-with-reject-call-vs-throwing-error), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25143476/asynchronous-exception-handling-with-bluebird-promises), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33445415/javascript-promises-reject-vs-throw) repeat that "if you're in any other asynchronous callback, you must use `reject`", but by "asynchronous" they're not referring to `async` functions, so I don't think their explanations apply here (and if they do, I don't understand how).

If instead of `throw` we use `reject`, the above code works fine. I'd like to understand, *fundamentally*, why `throw` doesn't work here. Thanks!

Comment: Just never use an async executor function. Why would you?

Comment: @Bergi Definitely might have fallen into an anti-pattern trap here. I can't see how I'd do this sort of thing differently (very likely due to being a promise newb)? --> http://jsbin.com/waqatagaqa/edit?js (note that `thing` is a library which I can't control/didn't make)

Comment: You want to make the `fn` function `async`, so that you can `await` the newly constructed promise and then do further things. The executor should not be `async`, and should do one thing only: wait for the event to happen and call `resolve`/`reject`. You might want to ask a new question with the full code so that I can provide a proper answer on that.

Comment: I think I'm misunderstanding you, and so I've created a seperate question as you suggested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43084557/using-promises-to-await-triggered-events Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is the async/await version of the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

[Never](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39409757/1048572) [ever](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43050114/1048572) use an `async function` as a `Promise` executor function <sub>(even when you can make it work<sup>1</sup>)</sub>!

<sub>[1: by calling `resolve` and `reject` instead of using `return` and `throw` statements]</sub>

> by "asynchronous" they're not referring to `async` functions, so I don't think their explanations apply here

They could as well. A simple example where it *cannot* work is

```
new Promise(async function() {
    await delay(…);
    throw new Error(…);
})
```

which is equivalent to

```
new Promise(function() {
    return delay(…).then(function() {
        throw new Error(…);
    });
})
```

where it's clear now that the `throw` is inside an asynchronous callback.

The [`Promise` constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28692824/1048572) can only catch *synchronous* exceptions, and an `async function` **never throws** - it always returns a promise (which might get rejected though). And that return value is ignored, as the promise is waiting for `resolve` to be called.

Comment: Future searchers should see [this follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43084557/using-promises-to-await-triggered-events) for more on the Promise anti-pattern.

Comment: You can actually do even shorter: ```return delay(…).then(function() {
        throw new Error(…);
    });```

Comment: @IvanPerevezentsev Isn't that the code in my answer, in the second non-working example?

Answer (score 6):

because the only way to "communicate" to the outside world from within a Promise executor is to use the `resolve` and `reject` functions. You could use the following for your example:

```
function fn() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    // there is no real reason to use an async executor here since there is nothing async happening
    try {
      throw new Error('<<fn error>>')
    } catch(error) {
      return reject(error);
    }
  });
}
```

An example would be when you want to do something that has convenient async functions, but also requires a callback. The following contrived example copies a file by reading it using the async `fs.promises.readFile` function with the callback based `fs.writeFile` function. In the real world, you would never mix `fs` functions like this because there is no need to. But some libraries like stylus and pug use callbacks, and I use something like this all the time in those scenarios.

```
const fs = require('fs');

function copyFile(infilePath, outfilePath) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      // the fs.promises library provides convenient async functions
      const data = await fs.promises.readFile(infilePath);
      // the fs library also provides methods that use callbacks
      // the following line doesn't need a return statement, because there is nothing to return the value to
      // but IMO it is useful to signal intent that the function has completed (especially in more complex functions)
      return fs.writeFile(outfilePath, data, (error) => {
        // note that if there is an error we call the reject function
        // so whether an error is thrown in the promise executor, or the callback the reject function will be called
        // so from the outside, copyFile appears to be a perfectly normal async function
        return (error) ? reject(error) : resolve();
      });
    } catch(error) {
      // this will only catch errors from the main body of the promise executor (ie. the fs.promises.readFile statement
      // it will not catch any errors from the callback to the fs.writeFile statement
      return reject(error);
      // the return statement is not necessary, but IMO communicates the intent that the function is completed
    }
  }
}
```

Apparently everyone says this is an anti-pattern, but I use it all the time when I want to do some async stuff before doing something that can only be done with a callback (not for copying files like my contrived example). I don't understand why people think it is an anti-pattern (to use an async promise executor), and haven't seen an example yet that has convinced me that it should be accepted as a general rule.

Comment: I do this thing all the time too. I recently tried to move my `await` statements to between the `function myfunc()...` and `return new Promise...`  and then to remove the `try/catch` altogether so that I could change my promise executor to not use `async` anymore, but it's just too clunky. Though, I'm really curious now if this example of yours (and what I do all over the place in my projects) would really get counted as part of this anti-pattern, and if so, why, and what (truly) better alternatives there would be.

Comment: I pratically use this all the time. It would be great why it is called an anti pattern

Answer (score 0):

A brief explanation:
when you need to expose some asynchronous operation status using reject and resolve methods you can use the async function itself to expose the status of that operation.

for example, here we're writing a signing function using Supabase SDK client to use in multiple parts of our app.

```
const signIn = async (
  email: string,
  password: string,
) => {
  const response =
    await supabaseClient.auth.signInWithPassword({
      email: email,
      password: password,
    });

 // save response.data.session.access_token in localstorage

  return response;
};
```

now we have a async function named signIn that we can somewhere else with all of the promises status

```
  try {
  const { data, error } = await signIn(email, password);
  if (error) {// Supabase internal error
    return alert(error.message);
  }
   // successful
   alert('successfully logged in');
  
} catch (err) { // like promise rejected 
  alert('Login Failed! Please try again.');
}
```