# Async/Await in a Class : unexpected token `this`

Tags: javascript, class, async-await

I am experimenting with async/await, I can't understand why this line :

```
resolvedValue = await this.tryToSolve()
```

gives me this error :

> Unexpected token this

```js
class Test {

 constructor() {
  this.method = 0
  this.checkLink()
 }

 async checkLink() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

   let resolvedValue

   for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    this.method = i
    resolvedValue = await this.tryToSolve()
    if (resolvedValue) break
   }
   console.log(`Method ${this.method} did the trick.`);
   resolve(resolvedValue)
  })
 }

 tryToSolve() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { // Resolves if this.method==1
   console.log(`Trying to solve with method ${this.method}...`);
   setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(!!this.method ? `http://www${this.method}.someurl.com` : false)
   }, 1000)
  })
 }
}

const test = new Test()
```

Does anyone know the correct syntax to store the result of an async method in a variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are awaiting inside an arrow function (you are crossing the boundary between async function and arrow function)

Comment: Precisely. `this` should work inside an arrow function (it should refer to the Class), so, what's the problem? Or rather, what's the solution?

Comment: `this` should work, but not `await`, because `await` doesn't work inside normal arrow functions. You can't just `await` because the body of the function is inside an async function. You can't cross function boundaries.

Comment: @Mörre As I said, I'm experimenting. This means, trying to get a better understanding. Instead of criticising my obvious lack of understanding, perhaps you could guide me to the solution instead, thanks.

Comment: @JeremyThille Check out this blog and its posts on promises (see the archive): http://2ality.com -- The author also has a free book about ES6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep things simple, it happens because when you create a Promise, in its' constructor you pass an arrow function, which contains `await` call. You must always put `async` keyword before the declaration of a function, that contains `await`.

So, instead of doing this

```
async checkLink() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        let resolvedValue

        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            this.method = i
            resolvedValue = await this.tryToSolve()
            if (resolvedValue) break
        }
        console.log(`Method ${this.method} did the trick.`);
        resolve(resolvedValue)
    })
}
```

Do it like this

```
checkLink() {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

        let resolvedValue

        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            this.method = i
            resolvedValue = await this.tryToSolve()
            if (resolvedValue) break
        }
        console.log(`Method ${this.method} did the trick.`);
        resolve(resolvedValue)
    })
}
```

More info: https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await#using-async-await

Comment: Why would you create a new promise??? Only to then create yet another promise in the inner function? Declare the outer function `async` and remove the `new Promise`. It already returns one! And the `async` allows the `await`. Instead or `resolve` use `return`.

Comment: Because my ultimate architecture goal is a main Promise that will get resolved when all the sub-promises are resolved. Feel free to demonstrate your knowledge with a snippet in another answer :)

Comment: If you have multiple promises you use `Promise.all` after creating them all in parallel.

Comment: @vanelizarov That was it, thanks. It became clear and obvious when I saw the solution.

Comment: @JeremyThille This is NOT a solution. It is a promise inside a promise, just ridiculous.

Comment: You keep criticising and saying this is not the solution. But you don't provide any.

Comment: @JeremyThille See what I wrote? You _should_ be able to interpret my very simple and basic suggestions. I provided all the details in my first reply - it is a complete description.

Comment: Yes, I saw that you energetically said that this is not a solution, and pointed to some blog. In the meantime, @vanelizarov gave me something that works, therefore I'll do with that, thanks.

Comment: @JeremyThille, `async` functions always return a promise. You don't have to explicitly create one. Whatever you return out of an `async` function will be the resolved value of the promise.

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. I do it because that's what I could find in the async/await tutorials, they promisify the awaited functions. I'll definitely try to remove the promises and simply return a value then, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Drop the [`new Promise` around the `await`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43083793/1048572)! You want only

```
async checkLink() {
    let resolvedValue
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        this.method = i
        resolvedValue = await this.tryToSolve()
        if (resolvedValue) break
    }
    console.log(`Method ${this.method} did the trick.`);
    return resolvedValue;
}
```

or much simpler

```
async checkLink() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        const value = await this.tryToSolve()
        if (value) {
            console.log(`Method ${i} did the trick.`);
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers, I'll give it a try later (I'm on holiday ;)

Comment: Tried it. The first method works, but the second one (replacing `break` with `return`) doesn't. The output is wrong then just stops without resolving. Thanks anyway for the first one :)