# JavaScript async, await, Promise, bug Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

It's needed to wait until the function getFile() ends. I call this async function in other function. In "async function getFile()" is bug:
"Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected."

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ShoppingCart extends LightningElement {

  async function getFile() {  // <= here is an error: "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected."
    let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
      //let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      //req.open('GET', "mycar.html");
      //req.onload = function() {
      //  if (req.status == 200) {myResolve(req.response);}
      //  else {myResolve("File not Found");}
      //};
      //req.send();
    });
    console.log(await myPromise);
  }

  handlePlaceOrder() {
    getFile();
  }
```

In this [example](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_async2) it's ok. What I have wrong?
Is it possible call async function in other than non async function?

I tried also an advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46565935/async-await-in-a-class-unexpected-token-this). To use first Promise, then async, but there is the same error:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ShoppingCart extends LightningElement {

  function getFile() {  // <= here is an error: "Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected."
    let myPromise = new Promise(async function(myResolve, myReject) {
      //let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      //req.open('GET', "mycar.html");
      //req.onload = function() {
      //  if (req.status == 200) {myResolve(req.response);}
      //  else {myResolve("File not Found");}
      //};
      //req.send();
    });
    console.log(await myPromise);
  }

  handlePlaceOrder() {
    getFile();
  }
```

I use VSCode.

Comment: Classes don't have functions, they have methods, so drop the `function` keyword and make it look like your `handlePlaceOrder` method. Also, add `async` in front of it if needed - `async getFile() { ... }`.

Comment: The `function` keyword is not used when declaring class methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Classes have methods, so you need to drop the `function` keyword when declaring a class method:

```js
class ShoppingCart extends LightningElement {
  getFile() { ... }
  handlePlaceOrder() { ... }
}
```

Also, there's an issue with how you're calling `getFile` inside `handlePlaceOrder`. After you fix your issue, `getFile` becomes a class method, you need to call it as `this.getFile()`, so your fixed class should look like the following:

```js
class ShoppingCard extends LightningElement {
  getFile() {
    return new Promise(
      function(resolve, reject) {
        let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("GET", "mycar.html");
        req.onload = function() {
          if (req.status == 200) {
            resolve(req.response);
          } else {
            reject("File not found");
          }
        }
        req.send();
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Then, since `getFile` is an asynchronous call that returns a `Promise`, you need to handle it as such inside your `handlePlaceOrder` method:

```js
class ShoppingCart extends LightningElement {
  getFile() {
    return new Promise(...);
  }

  handlePlaceOrder() {
    this.getFile()
      .then(function(result) {
        // do whatever
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle errors appropriately
      })
  }
}
```

Alternatively, make your `handlePlaceOrder` function `async` if it's making it easier for you to work with `Promise`s:

```js
class ShoppingCart extends LightningElement {
  getFile() {
    return new Promise(...);
  }

  async handlePlaceOrder() {
    try {
      let file = await this.getFile();
      // do whatever
    } catch (error) {
      // handle errors appropriately
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This line `return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) => {` should be without **=>**, no? I mean it should be: `return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {`?

Comment: @Elo yes, that is my mistake, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit: Look at goto1's solution it is more detailed

Like the comments suggest drop the function keyword. The keyword is only needed if you declare a function in a regular javascript outside of a class.

Furthermore you can't just await a promise. You need to call your promise and then await its result. This can be done like this: `myPromise.then(result => {})`.

Another thing in your function is that you aren't returning a value in your promise. You should call `myResolve` to pass the result of a successfull execution and `myReject` for an error.

You class should look like this:

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ShoppingCart extends LightningElement {

  async getFile() {
    let myPromise = new Promise(function(myResolve, myReject) {
      let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.open('GET', "mycar.html");
      req.onload = function() {
        if (req.status == 200) {myResolve(req.response);}
        else {myResolve("File not Found");}
      };
      req.send();
    });
    myPromise.then(response => {
        console.log(response)
    });
  }

  handlePlaceOrder() {
    getFile();
  }
}
```