# js async/await throws error on using this keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, ecmascript-2017

So, here's the code

```
let x = await this.storeFileName(fileName);
```

So, I've declared the `storeFileName` function as async and I'm also returning a promise and everything till here is fine. But I'm getting an error that says :

`SyntaxError: Unexpected token this` which is pointing to the 'this' followed by the await keyword

Btw I'm using an ES6 class and the this keyword refers to the object of that class.

It works without the await keyword but if I put await it throws an error.

What am I doing wrong? Everything seems correct. Can someone throw some light on me.

UPDATE :

These are the two functions.

```
   async encodeName(x){
     return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes192', this.PASSWORD);
        let encrypted = cipher.update(x,'utf8', 'hex');
        encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
        if(encrypted.length>240){
         let x = await this.storeFileName(encrypted);
         resolve(`@Fn ${x}`);
      }
      resolve(encrypted);
     });
   }

   async storeFileName(x){
     return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
      let doc = { encName: x };
      filesDb = new db(`${this.mntpnt}/__CORE_rigel.pro/x100.db`);
      filesDb.insert(doc,(err,newdoc)=>{
        err?reject():resolve(newdoc._id);
      });   
     });
   }
```

**Btw, I'm doing this on node.js**

UPDATE 2 :

Here is the error message

```
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
/home/teja/Documents/Rigel/components/diskEncryptor.js:32
        let x = await this.storeFileName(encrypted);
                      ^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token this
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/teja/Documents/Rigel/index.js:4:23)
```

Comment: Do you have declared as `async` the function where `let x = await this.storeFileName(fileName);` is?

Comment: _"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/)."_

Comment: @Maluen It's not required but yea I did.

Comment: @Teja `It's not required but yea I did`  It certainly is required, you can't use `await` without marking the function your calling it from as `async`.

Comment: We need to see more code. What does the implementation of `storeFileName` look like. The `this` keyword in __JavaScript__ is the context of the scope, so where are you using it? Again, we need to see more code in order to help.

Comment: @Keith No, what I meant was I also declared the function I'm using the await keyword in as async . I ofcourse declared `storeFileName` as async

Comment: @Teja,  no not `storeFileName`..   The function your calling it from..

Comment: Everyone, I updated the question with the complete functions

Comment: A Promise callback is also a function, it's not marked as `async`,,. And in any case why not just use `async` ?  `new Promise` is not required and would be pointless.

Comment: @Teja  `async storeFileName(x){ return new Promise`  Please note what this code is saying,  return a promise that returns a promise.  Understand that bit and you should be able to fix your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new function

`return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{`

you should declare that function as async too:

`return new Promise(async (resolve,reject)=>{`

The new function will be

```
async function encodeName(x){
 return new Promise(async (resolve,reject)=>{
    const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes192', this.PASSWORD);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(x,'utf8', 'hex');
    encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
    if(encrypted.length>240){
     let x = await this.storeFileName(encrypted);
     resolve(`@Fn ${x}`);
    }
    resolve(encrypted);
 });
}
```

Comment: That would stop the error, but removing the `Promise` in the first is what's needed.

Comment: @keith Lol, but seriously It printed the exact same error message.

Comment: @Teja,  update your snippet, and show what you initially did.  You don't want to be mixing Promise constructor with `async` it's meaningless.

Comment: @Pascut It's not.

Comment: @Bergi You can solve the problem by removing the `new Promise` antipattern completely (and you should), but the fundamental reason for the `SyntaxError` is not adding async to the created arrow function.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, it seems a little bit tricky explaining what you need to do to make your functions `async` compatible.

So here I've updated your functions to show what I would do.

Notice the `util.promisify`, this is now baked into a latest version of Node.

```
async encodeName(x){
  const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes192', this.PASSWORD);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(x,'utf8', 'hex');
  encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
  if(encrypted.length>240){
    let x = await this.storeFileName(encrypted);
    return `@Fn ${x}`;
  }
  return encrypted;
}

async storeFileName(x){
  let doc = { encName: x };
  filesDb = new db(`${this.mntpnt}/__CORE_rigel.pro/x100.db`);
  pinsert = util.promisify(filesDb.insert);
  const newdoc = await pinsert(doc);
  return newdoc._id;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use `await` in the executor function of the `new Promise` constructor that is not declared `async`. And [you should not](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43083793/1048572) anyway!

Use

```
async encodeName(x) {
  // no Promise constructor here!
  const cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes192', this.PASSWORD);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(x, 'utf8', 'hex');
  encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
  if (encrypted.length > 240) {
    let x = await this.storeFileName(encrypted);
    return `@Fn ${x}`);
  }
  return encrypted;
}
storeFileName(x) {
  // no unnecessary async here
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let doc = { encName: x };
    filesDb = new db(`${this.mntpnt}/__CORE_rigel.pro/x100.db`);
    filesDb.insert(doc, (err, newdoc) => {
      err ? reject(err) : resolve(newdoc._id);
    });
  });
}
```