# Promises and cycles

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

There's a chain of promises, the first takes user's id from data base after i need to get his groups and names of constructor from data base 
And these can be multiple copies 
As a result cycle into cycle. eventually I receive object only of one user

```js
async(takeIds()
  .then(ids => {
    // console.log("ids", ids);
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
      data.id = ids[i];
      await (takeIdvk(ids[i])
        .then(idm => {
          data.idvk = idm;
          takeIdg(data.id)
            .then(res => {
              takeNamesCycle(res, data)
                .then(data => {
                  console.log("data", data);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  console.log(err);
                });
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log(err);
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        }));
    }
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }));
```

And function takeNamesCycle cos it differs from other
( in the rest simple requests to data base)

```js
var takeNamesCycle = async(function(arr, obj) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var idg = arr[i];
      await (takeNames(arr[i])
        .then(names => {
          obj.idg[idg] = names;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        }));
    }
    resolve(obj);
  });
});
```

Is it possible to simplify this? 
I'd be grateful

Comment: You just need to catch at the highest level.

Comment: @JonasW. What do u mean?

Comment: Yea I agree with jonas, it does not look like you are doing much else with the intermediate `catch`s, so just remove all but the last

Comment: `await`  throws the rejection reason of an awaited promise. Without intervention this rejects the promise returned by the async function for the same reason. A single catch clause on the promise returned by the top level `async` function call should catch all uncaught rejections below it. Putting a catch clause on an awaited promise converts rejection into fulfillment. with the risk that if `await` returns after rejection, processing continues with garbage data.

Comment: @traktor53, so i need to use only one `catch` in my first promise? I will try and write here

Answer (score 1):

Consider using real `async`/`await` syntax instead of a library with `async()` and `await()` functions.

```
const ids = await takeIds();
// console.log("ids", ids);
try {
  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    data.id = ids[i];
    const idem = await takeIdvk(ids[i]);
    data.idvk = idm;
    const res = await takeIdg(data.id);
    console.log("data", await takeNamesCycle(res, data));
  }
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

and make sure to [avoid the `Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43083793/1048572)

```
async function takeNamesCycle(arr, obj) {
  for (const idg of arr) {
    const names = await takeNames(idg);
    obj.idg[idg] = names;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: i lost to say that i've got an old version of node... 4.2.6. And i don't know is it possible to update it without problems

Comment: Yes, you should definitely update. I can't think of any problems it would cause. If you can't, you still can use a transpiler.

Answer (score 0):

The posted code is mixing promise chain style of code within `await` and `async` functions within bad code.

First `await` does not permit `.then` or `.catch` methods to be called on the value it returns. The reason is that the value returned by `await` is **never** a promise. `await` only resumes execution after a successful promise operation and returns the result of the operation. So for example

```
await (takeIdvk(ids[i])
.then(idm => {           // incorrect
     data.idvk = idm;
     // ... more code
```

becomes

```
let idm = await takeIdvk(ids[i])   // await returns fulfilled value
data.idvk = idm;
// ... more code
```

In other words, code to handle data for a successful operation is written inline after `await` instead of in a separate `onfulfilled` handler passed as a parameter to `.then`.

**Promise Rejections**

If the promise being waited on becomes rejected, the `await` operator throws the rejection reason without resuming function execution.

The rejection can be caught in a try/catch block in order to ignore the error, repeat the operation, or replace it with a different operation as determined by application requirements. E.G.

```
let idm;
try {
    idm = await takeIdvk(ids[i])   // await returns fulfilled value
    data.idvk = idm;
    // ... more code
} catch( err) {
    console.log( "ignoring error + err);
    // the value of idm is undefined
}
```

On the other hand, if rejection is to be considered fatal don't put `await` inside a `try/catch` block - the thrown value will be caught and used to reject the promise returned by the async function, much like throwing an error inside a `then` or `catch` handler.

If calls to async functions are nested, each called using `await` without any `try/catch` blocks, rejection errors will bubble up from deeply nested functions and reject the promise returned by the outermost async function call. A single `.catch` clause on the outermost promise can be used to prevent uncaught promise rejections and notify that a failure occurred.

**Conclusion**

Try writing the code using plain promise chains if you are more familiar with that syntax. By all means continue with converting it to async/await syntax but be aware that `async/await` is an *alternative* syntax and they don't mix well in the same function. As already stated by @Bergi , returning a new promise from an async function is an anti pattern - async functions return a promise already.