# Trying to understand promise based javascript code

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

I have the following promise code in a [existing open source library](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-react-native-starter/blob/master/client/lib/Categories/Auth/Components/Examples/SignIn.js):

simplified code is following:

```
class SignIn extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // What is the underlying type of this.resolver ?
    this.resolver = Promise.resolve();
  }

  handleMFACancel() {
    // Is resolver a function ?
    this.resolver(null);
  }
  handleMFASuccess(session) {
    // Is resolver a function ?
    this.resolver(session);

  }
}
```

I do not understand how we could use `this.resolver` as a function.

It is not supposed to be a resolved promise or maybe simply a promise.

Comment: `The Promise.resolve(value) method returns a Promise object` <- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Comment: `this.resolver()` returns a Promise object. If you want to invoke the method/function again, assign `this.resolver = Promise.resolve` (without parentheses)

Comment: Well if you just try the code you will see that it throws a type error, you cannot use a promise as a function. So yes, the code is just broken.

Comment: Notice that they [overwrite `this.resolver` in line 59](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-react-native-starter/blob/master/client/lib/Categories/Auth/Components/Examples/SignIn.js#L59) with what is presumably a callback function. Of course all of this, especially [passing an `async function` as a `new Promise` executor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43083793/1048572) in line 58, is just horrible horrible code.

Comment: @Bergi you're right. I simply do not understand why it is initialized that way.

Comment: @OlivierMATROT Why? Because the author was clueless, or because it the code was edited and this was forgotten. It's definitely a mistake. If you want to help the project, report it as a bug - that's why it's open source.

Comment: Why the downvote ? Please explain.

Comment: @Bergi I'll do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve `Promise.resolve()` returns a **new Promise object**

Typically this is used to create a uniform API, because the Promise returned is one that will instantly be resolved with the value provided (in your case there is no value - but you could have used `Promise.resolve('some-value')`.

What you probably want to do here is control when cancel or success should be handled by implementing your own code to do the actual login and setting the resolver promise to your own specific logic, e.g (pseudocode):

```
this.resolver = http.someCallToGetSession().then(({ result, session }) => {
  if (result.val === 'ok') {
    return session;
  } else {
    throw new Error('Session not found');
  }
});
```