# Using Object.assign() to assign a number results in the object reference being undefined

Tags: ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, assign

I apologise for the sheer amount of code contained here but I wanted to disclose everything. No matter what I try I cannot get `Object.assign()` to assign a whole number to the given key, despite the same operation working perfectly to assign a floating point number on the next line.

This code contains all needed references so it's clunky (part of my debugging kit):

```
let markers = []
let cumulativeTimes = {}

const randomWholeNumber = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)

const time = (marker) => { markers[marker] = process.hrtime() }

const timeEnd = (marker, cumulative = true) => {
  const hrend = process.hrtime(markers[marker])
  const precision = 3
  const seconds = hrend[0] // already an int
  const milliSeconds = +(hrend[1] / 1000000).toFixed(precision) // unary plus converts string result to int

  console.log(`Seconds is ${seconds} with type ${typeof(seconds)}`) // outputs "number" - always!

  if (cumulative) {
    let mark = cumulativeTimes[marker]
    mark ? mark.s += seconds : Object.assign(cumulativeTimes, { [marker]: { s: seconds } } ) // <-- It's a trap!
    mark ? mark.ms += milliSeconds : Object.assign(cumulativeTimes, { [marker]: { ms: milliSeconds } } )
    mark = cumulativeTimes[marker]
    console.log(`${mark.s}s, ${mark.ms}ms -- ${marker}`) // outputs undefineds, then NaNs (for seconds)
  } else {
    console.log(`${seconds}s, ${milliSeconds}ms -- ${marker}`)
  }
}

const someLongOp = () => {
  time('someLongOp')
  return new Promise ( async (resolve) => {
    await setTimeout(timeEnd, randomWholeNumber(1000, 5000), 'someLongOp')
    resolve()
  })
}

const test = async (count) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    await someLongOp()
  }
}

test(2)
```

Sample Output:

```
Seconds is 2 with type number
undefineds, 993.351ms -- someLongOp
Seconds is 3 with type number
NaNs, 1476.091ms -- someLongOp
```

Now I understand why the second value is NaN (because on the second run of `timeEnd()` the "mark.s" key exists however it references the value `undefined`, and performing any arithmetic on undef results in `NaN`).

What I don't get is why, when `seconds` is a simple unsigned integer which is confirmed to be a number, this value isn't properly assigned on the first run of the `timeEnd()`. Even weirder, as we can see from the milliseconds output, this exact same operation works fine for a floating point number... although they are both technically [double-precision 64-bit unsigned ints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Number_type).

Change the default value of `cumulative` to false and the seconds are output and displayed as expected, so I'm 95% sure it's something going on during the `Object.assign()` part.

Will definitely award a bounty to this once it qualifies... looking forward to understanding what on earth is happening!

Comment: Uh, [`new Promise ( async (resolve) => {`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43083793/1048572) and [`await setTimeout`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33289726/1048572)? That's not how promises work at all.

Comment: If `marker` is a string, don't make `markers` an array. Use an object or a Map.

Comment: The debug file doesn't even make it into the repo let alone production my friend ;) it's full of whacky things. Pay it no never mind - you spotted the object overwrite - thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with doubles versus integers. It's just that your code

> ```
> mark ? mark.s += seconds : Object.assign(cumulativeTimes, { [marker]: { s: seconds } } ) // <-- It's a trap!
> mark ? mark.ms += milliSeconds : Object.assign(cumulativeTimes, { [marker]: { ms: milliSeconds } } )
> ```

is wrong. Let's desugar it:

```
if (mark)
   mark.s += seconds;
else
   cumulativeTimes[marker] = { s: seconds };
if (mark)
   mark.ms += milliSeconds;
else
   cumulativeTimes[marker] = { ms: milliSeconds };
```

That's obviously not working, overwriting the object with the `s` property with the one with the `ms` property. Remember that `Object.assign` does not recursively merge!

What you actually want is

```
if (mark) {
    mark.s += seconds;
    mark.ms += milliSeconds;
} else {
    cumulativeTimes[marker] = {
        s: seconds,
        ms: milliSeconds
    };
}
```

Comment: I went way too deep down the rabbit hole on that one. That fixed it, thank you