# How to try catch a recursive function called in an async event handler which is wrapped in Promise.all

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

What I'm trying to do is upload multiple file chunks at the same time and then retry each individual chunk 5 times if it fails, I've recreated this example code in ts playground and it works exactly how my actual code does, I omitted using XMLHttpRequest for brevity.

Here is my example code:

```
class FileUploader {
    onSuccess: ((this: FileUploader) => void) | null;
    onFail: ((this: FileUploader) => void) | null;

    constructor() {
        this.onSuccess = null;
        this.onFail = null;
    }

    run() {
        // const num = Math.random();
        // if (num > 0.4) {
        //     this.onGood?.();
        // } else {
        //     this.onBad?.();
        // }
        // the above code simulated a request failing or succeding.
        this.onFail?.();
    }
}



async function uploadFile(name: string, retryCount = 0) {
    return new Promise<void>(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const runner = new FileUploader();
        runner.onSuccess = async () => {
            await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, 500));
            resolve();
        }
        runner.onFail = async () => {
            if (retryCount < 5) {
                console.log(`Ran ${name}, ${retryCount}`);
                const newDelay = Math.pow(2, retryCount) * 100;
                await new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, newDelay));
                await uploadFile(name, retryCount + 1);
            }
            console.log("rejected", name);
            reject("error");
        }
        runner.run();
    });
}

async function main() {
    try {
        await Promise.all([uploadFile("file1"), uploadFile("file2"), uploadFile("file3")])
        console.log("success")
    }
    catch (ex) {
        console.log("error")
        console.log(ex);
    }
}

main();
```

What I want to do is catch the error in the main function, how can I do this?

Comment: I'm not sure why you need `new Promise` and a recursive call, but if so, then you probably want `.catch(reject)` in your recursive step, otherwise you're just failing to reject anything but the innermost promise.  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX0Row). Does that fully address the question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz The reason I used `new Promise` was because I need to loop over an array of chunks and upload them all at the same time using Promise.all, then and the recursive call is done in order to retry in case of a network error. Your code seems to work except that the other promises keep running even after one fails and "error" is logged twice, I would expect it to only log "error" once but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Surely that could all be done in a single async function with a counter.  But I suppose it's beyond the scope of the question.  Which "other promises" keep running? You have three sets of promises, do you mean each set continues to run after one if its members fails?  Or do you mean that the second and third sets run after the first set fails? ... "error is logged twice?" you have two lines that log error, why would you expect one of them not to be run?

Comment: @jcalz Sorry let me clarify, from what I understood if any promise in `Promise.All`, rejects than the promise from `Promise.All` would reject and all of promise in the array that was passed to it would stop running. "error" is only logged once, in the catch block of the main function, I log "reject" in the onFail.

Comment: ① "all of promise in the array that was passed to it would stop running" That's not how it works; promises that are already running cannot be terminated. the promise returned by `all()` will immediately reject when any of its input promises rejects, but nothing happens to the input promises. But this is really out of scope for the question as asked, isn't it? ② The string "reject" appears nowhere in your code, but "error" appears twice. Maybe you should change them to "error1" and "error2" and figure out why you see both of them. Again, this is out out scope for the question.

Comment: (see prev comment) Is it possible for us to separate what your original question was from what happened after you overcame the problem there? If not, this is going to become an extended one-on-one support session which is not the point of Stack Overflow. Right now the goal should be to figure out whether my suggestion actually addresses the problem and whether an answer to that effect might be acceptable, or if there's something it doesn't address. Could you tell me which of those options we're looking at?

Comment: @jcalz Ah ok I understand how `Promise.All` works now, I was also confused because I called `reject("error")` and then in the main function console logged the string "error" as well as the error from the catch so I saw "error" twice, your code seems to work so thank you.

Comment: So if I wrote up an answer saying that you need something like `.catch(reject)` in order for your outer promises to reject when inner ones do, that would fully address the question? I'm not missing anything and the subsequent stuff about `Promise.all` and `"error"` are not an obstacle?

Comment: @jcalz Yes `.catch(reject)` worked and solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [`Promise` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise) is tricky and usually not recommended. See [Is creating a new promise with a async function call bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50554373/2887218). One of the main issues is that it's easy to fail to reject the promise if something goes wrong. Indeed, when your innermost call to `uploadFile()` rejects, the line

```
await uploadFile(name, retryCount + 1);
```

will throw an error inside the `Promise` constructor.  And this is not the same as rejecting the promise. You can't reject that promise unless you actually call `reject()`.  One way to avoid that is to [`catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) any rejection of `uploadFile()` with the `reject` function from your `Promise` constructor:

```
await uploadFile(name, retryCount + 1).catch(reject);
```

Once you make this change you'll see all the rejections bubble up, followed by the rejection of `Promise.all()`:

```
[LOG]: "rejected",  "file1"  // 5 
[LOG]: "rejected",  "file1"  // 4
[LOG]: "rejected",  "file1"  // 3
[LOG]: "rejected",  "file1"  // 2
[LOG]: "rejected",  "file1"  // 1
[LOG]: "rejected",  "file1"  // 0
[LOG]: "error message", "error"
```

So that's the answer to the question as asked.

---

Again, you should reconsider any code that deals with promises inside of `new Promise()`, especially given how easy it is to get error handling wrong.  But since that is out of scope for the question as asked, I'm not going to digress further.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiCWICmBVADiA9mAJkgTtAN4BQ050mAdgMoCuwwSUAXNABTsAuAFvBGwTJ0WXAQCU0ALwA+aADdM8HJIA+0KnRAgA3GQrVYYRG069+gxKgzY8+SbIVKV0dZu1795YNQhd8DFyY+OySpBQR0OYQAHTU9IzMMFIaWrpekdFxVEaI0qkeGQC+JBkBVKHEGREA9DXQPlR+qQC2+QCyYLwx+GBUOJgtoXqRFHXQ8ABmHJptcgAMMQAsYdVj9RFZ1ADimJg4APwxw2vk40XQSCAQSFWjZxsUW1QAQrhHJ-fQ56ff9by3MAAI0w8luPjw0Ag8BaWi6SBw0DA0HwSAAjnRmFxoJNjCB4FQAOaUQgQBhMHAEwkxX7PXIgD7iEYUEolUokSAATyowBxdB5XHg1GgdBsuCESHYVDALSQbD8+CpABoUUh-JyAMKYfnYlLzVYRVFcOj4KgaJAAd2gAAV8IN+EgADyKZQydhcnkcVEQTAgMEq1EAKyQwC4Djk4XujWa5SoBHycatEpEtgIn3usYI2QSTCg+Q9vMqjkjX3IYAtxmxiZtdpaDs43vDULVABUYUhtVx2N6VQBWeb6pm-Q3MX1g9OjEpfTP4bL0-MQbmFpsl0tTL1q-Ca7VUbGO6C9g2l0bR31IGJYQnsAAGACU+tAACREaWyooq59GrdanVFa9D48T18KtLQAESuMBOQ6LoeBiNBMAtdgACYA03bcdUkAAqaAAEYB2ZQCKHLStzStW17RuBtmCbG4uDbWVO27ZgVUTcDwE5cQAMIoiK3gbFRVEHAJSlGUkFQ9Uf13aAAGpcPEGJgC6YAeCY4NQy448p0A09kAvTArwAIiDEMuARAyWNE8Tvx3MMCNLYzQ3YAyCDtfADI0yItNGGcen5CdoCKIc2QLPkBSFM0WmMCoj3IdU7nuYi+JrCjzzAbR2AAbQE2xhIMyYrBw9yVWy8UrCc-LkCQoqRTFISyryqwAGZ3IAXXEX4dPPS8nLJRIoHc4oMkUrhlI4JAAA8YsiTq9MMlzgmgWUoDAQkkHMy5Jrs1lSkiglhiAA)