# ESLint reports a promise misuse for code I consider ok

Tags: javascript, eslint

In a symbol table implementation I have this method:

```js
    public getAllSymbols(type?: typeof Symbol, localOnly = false): Promise<Set<Symbol>> {
        const promise = super.getAllSymbols(type ?? Symbol, localOnly);

        return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try {
                let result = await promise;

                if (!localOnly) {
                    this.dependencies.forEach(async (dependency) => {
                        result = new Set([...result, ...await dependency.getAllSymbols(type, localOnly)]);
                    });
                }

                resolve(result);
            } catch (reason) {
                reject(reason);
            }
        });
    }
```

which works fine, however ESLint reports 2 promise misuses:

[image]

> Promise returned in function argument where a void return was expected. `no-misused-promises`

What's wrong with this code and how would I have to write it to get rid of the linter error?

Comment: Would imagine that the issue is that the executor function now returns a promise (as it is declared async) and so does the forEach argument.  Neither of these functions are expected to return anything.

Comment: I don't see a return, except for the one which the function returns. Looking at the [eslint error description](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/v4.31.0/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-misused-promises.md) uses as one example pretty much what I have done myself.

Comment: The eslint error description tells you that your code will be reported as an error - it is under examples of incorrect code. making a function async automatically wraps the return value in a Promise - even if you have no return statement in your function - in which case it will return Promise<undefined>......you can always await an async function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problems in your code:

- Executor function shouldn't be `async` - it's an [anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43083793/6094348)
- As `super.getAllSymbol(...)` already returns a promise, so no need to wrap it in a promise constructor - it's another [anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it). Call the `then()` method directly on the promise returned by `super.getAllSymbol(...)`
- Using `async-await` with `forEach()` won't give you the expected result because the callback function of `forEach()` won't wait for the awaited promise to settle - it will just continue to the next iteration.

  You can use `Promise.all()` along with the `map()` method to get the expected output.

  You could also use `for-of` loop but using `Promise.all()` is better if you don't want all the promises to settle in a sequential manner.

Your code could be re-written as (types removed for simplicity):

```
public getAllSymbols(type, localOnly = false) {

     const promise = super.getAllSymbols(type ?? Symbol, localOnly);

     return promise
         .then(result => {
             if (!localOnly) {
                 return Promise.all(this.dependencies.map(dep => (
                    dep.getAllSymbols(type, localOnly))
                 )))
                 .then(resultArr => {
                     return new Set([...result, ...resultArr]);
                 });
             }
             else {
                 return result;
             }                       
         });
}
```

or you could use the `async-await` syntax:

```
public async getAllSymbols(type, localOnly = false) {

    const result = await super.getAllSymbols(type ?? Symbol, localOnly);

    if (!localOnly) {
        const resultArr = await Promise.all(this.dependencies.map(dep => ( 
            dep.getAllSymbols(type, localOnly)
        )));

        return new Set([...result, ...resultArr]);                         
    }

    return result;                   
}
```

I have removed the `catch` block because, in my opinion, calling code should handle the errors, if any.

Above function can be called as:

```
getAllSymbols(...)
   .then(result => { ... })
   .catch(error => { ... });
```

or you can use `async-await` syntax:

```
try {
    const result = await getAllSymbols(...);
    ...
   
} catch (error) {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Note: you may want to fix the code for the set merges. `resultArr` is not an array of symbols but a an array of sets of symbols. So you need a loop over the array to construct the final set.